# Cordova not upgrading to the latest version

Tags: android, cordova, fedora

I am trying to upgrade Cordova from version 3.5.0-0.2.7 to 3.6 or later.
But when I do:

```
[root@localhost home]# npm install -g cordova
/usr/local/bin/cordova -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/bin/cordova
cordova@4.1.2 /usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova
├── underscore@1.7.0
├── q@1.0.1
├── nopt@3.0.1 (abbrev@1.0.5)
└── cordova-lib@4.1.2 (osenv@0.1.0, properties-parser@0.2.3, bplist-parser@0.0.6, mime@1.2.11, semver@2.0.11, unorm@1.3.3, rc@0.5.2, shelljs@0.3.0, dep-graph@1.1.0, npmconf@0.1.16, xcode@0.6.7, d8@0.4.4, tar@1.0.2, elementtree@0.1.5, request@2.47.0, glob@4.0.6, plist@1.1.0, npm@1.3.4, cordova-js@3.7.2)

[root@localhost home]# cordova -v
3.5.0-0.2.7
```

You see it still shows the old version. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try using sudo npm install -g cordova

Comment: Nobody has answered this yet?